# add data to a local JSON file in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a question please,is it possible to add a Data to a local JSON file,I tried with this code:

Controller.js:

```
  $scope.creerOperation= function(article) {
    article.codeOperation = $scope.articleCourante.codeOperation;
    article.operation = $scope.articleCourante.operation;

    $http
       .post("./json/Options/create.json",article)
        .success(
        function(newArticle) {$scope.annulerAjout();});}
```

MyView.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="articleCourante.codeOperation" />
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="articleCourante.operation" /> 
    <button ng-click="creerOperation(articleCourante)">Add</button>                     
</div>
```

create.json:

```
 {
        "codeOperation": "codeOperation1",
        "operation": "operation1",
    }
```

but any data I have put in input Texts doesn't be added in create.json file
any help please,how can I correct my code to do that??
thanks for help

Comment: You can only on select browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Comment: thanks Jorg for your reply,but I didn't understand your reply :)

Comment: Editing a local file means accessing someone's local file system. You can only do that in a few browsers like Chrome (as per the link). Usually people use databases. Or maybe check [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: what about Sir to test that in a local JSON file,in my PC only before putting the URL of web Service,is it possible in this case?